# Application quits *** Assertion failure in -[UITableView _configureCellForDisplay:forIndexPath:]

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

This is my code for `UITableView`. Whenever I load the view, I recieve the following error:

> *** Assertion failure in -[UITableView _configureCellForDisplay:forIndexPath:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3512.30.14/UITableView.m:7962
>   UITableView (; layer = ; contentOffset: {0, 0}; contentSize: {343, 190}>) failed to obtain a cell from its dataSource ()

The method to create a table is the same. I have been working with tableviews for a long time. However, I wasn't able to figure out that's wrong with this.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 3;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    switch (indexPath.row) {
        case 0:
            return 70;
            break;
        case 1:
            return 50;
            break;
        case 3:
            return 50;
            break;
        default:
            return 70;
            break;
    }
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *Id = @"CellID2";
    UITableViewCell * cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:Id forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if(cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:Id];
    }

    UILabel *object = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:1];
    UILabel *discription = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:2];
    object.text = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    switch (indexPath.row) {
        case 0:
            discription.text = self.Location;
            break;
        case 1:
            discription.text = self.LocationType;
            break;
        case 3:
            discription.text = self.rating;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    return nil;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The message:

> failed to obtain a cell from its dataSource

means you are returning `nil` for your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method.

Change `return nil;` to `return cell;` at the end of your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method.